# How to remove duplicate select option except selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there a way where I can remove the duplicate of the selected option in select dropdown with jQuery/javascript?

I have already tried using `if/else` in PHP but that is a long line of code for 12 files.

I also have tried this code which I got from here

```
var optionValues =[];
$('#locationList option').each(function(){
   if($.inArray(this.value, optionValues) >-1){
      $(this).remove()
   }else{
      optionValues.push(this.value);
   }
});
```

which doesn't work for me because this code only removes all the duplicate regardless of the selected

For example, I have this line of code

```
<select name="select">
<option value="one">One</option>
<option value="two">Two</option>
<option value="three">Three</option>
<option value="one" selected>One</option>
</select>
```

Reason for the last `option` was because I just echoed the value from the database and set it to selected for it to display the current value of that select dropdown.

I expect the output to be that the duplicate of the option that has `selected` attribute will be removed from the dropdown list

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use PHP to not display duplicate items in the first place? Should be fairly easy. You can find 100s of examples of that online, I'm quite sure. When you're adding items to the list, check each one to see if it matches the currently selected option. If it does, add the `selected` attribute to that option as you're printing it. No need to add a whole new option! (And I can't see why it would be a "long" line of code either. Hopefully you're using a loop in PHP to populate your list??)

Comment: You are selecting options from a select element with the id "locationList". Change the id or add it to your select tag.

Comment: And wouldn't it to write code of selected at the top of all options?

Comment: What you should do is select the corresponding option instead of inserting a new one and then remove the duplicate one.

Comment: @ADyson unfortunately, I'm not using loop to populate the list

Comment: @MjMendoza to which the obvious question would be...why not? Normally the possible options would be stored in the DB and you'd loop through them to generate `<option>` elements for each one. Or if the options are hard-coded and never need to be changed, you could replace the DB table with an array in PHP. If you've hard-coded the`<option>` tags directly, then this makes it harder to do what you need to do in this case. Change to using a loop to generate the options based on some data source (either DB or array or file or whatever) and then you can check the selected values in the loop. Simple

Comment: @ADyson will try to re-structure the application, this is an old application and I'm tasked to stabilized it before re-platforming it to a latest language. So that's why I am seeking for an easy way here.

Answer (score 0):

**This code will help you.**

```
var obj = {};
$("select").children("option").each(function(){
 let val = $(this).attr("value");
 if(obj[val]){
   if($(this).is(":selected")){
    obj[val].remove();
    obj[val] = $(this);
   }else if(obj[val].is(":selected")){
    $(this).remove()
   }else{
    $(this).remove();
   }
 }
 obj[val] = $(this);
});
```